# Why Is wp.editor Not Adding the ”Add Media” Button When I Initialize It?

Tags: javascript, block-editor, wp-editor

[image: This the problem]
I have a custom post type with a custom field that has an array of key-value pairs (Locations). I'm trying to load the wp.editor for one of the key-value pairs (Description) and it's working except it's not adding the "Add Media" button when I do it on the JavaScript side. I'm doing it in two ways: PHP when the location is already in the database and JavaScript for new locations. It's adding the "Add Media" button for forms rendered by PHP but the wp.editor on the JavaScript side doesn't add it.

Here are my codes on the JavaScript side:

```
// Initialize the WordPress editor for the new location
var settings = {
  tinymce: {
    toolbar1: 'formatselect | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist | blockquote | link unlink | | pastetext removeformat | code',
    toolbar2: '',
    toolbar3: '',
    toolbar4: '',
    content_style: 'body { font-family: San Francisco, Segoe UI, DejaVu Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }'
  },
  textareaName: 'guide-locations-' + i + '-description',
  mediaButtons: true,
  textareaRows: 5
};
wp.editor.initialize('guide-locations-' + i + '-description', settings);
```

I've tried both media_buttons and mediaButtons but none of them work. I also have the following enqueued successfully:

```
// Enqueue media editor
wp_enqueue_media();
wp_enqueue_script('media-buttons');
wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-edit-post' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-i18n' );
wp_enqueue_script('media-editor');
wp_enqueue_editor();
```

Can somebody please help me?